# c# How to make window follow another?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, move, visual-studio-2015

Question: How do i get notepad to follow my main window when it moves? Running the program yields two windows side by side, yet as soon as the mainwindow moves by click-hold, notepad is left in the dust, im trying to find a way for notepad to follow it but keep it tightly next to the main window as how the program ran.
I had success with making notepad move if mainwindow moves, but it's just not proportional because notepad would move to another direction at different speeds so it was not enough.
summary: i need a function that makes notepad constantly move (update) it's position relative to mainwindows position as a user is click-moving the window.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MoveWindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Height="500" Width="500">

 </Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MoveWindow
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Process notepadProcess = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Left = 0;
        Top = 0;
        //these variables are to find the location of mainWindow and add it to it's width --> (x) so that notepad knows where to position itself next to mainwindow

        var xx = Application.Current.MainWindow.Top;
        var yy = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left;
        var zz = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width;
        var answer = ((yy + zz) + ((yy + zz)*.5));

        int myInt = (int)answer;


        var notepadProcess = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        if (notepadProcess != null)
        {
            notepadProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

            // This is the function that sets location of notepad, myInt = 750(x)
            CustomMove(notepadProcess, myInt, 0, 500, 500);
        }
    }

    public void CustomMove(Process process, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        var ok = MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, x, y, width, height, true);
        if (ok == false)
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't move your window!");



    }
    //DLL call to make 'moveWindow' functional
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `LocationChanged` event on the `window` you can listen to and update notepad's location every time the event is raised.

Comment: you are warm, using the LocationChanged, moving right to left notepad window will move perfectly along with mainwindow, moving mainwindow top/bottom, notepad does not move :/ im almost there

Comment: Your original code passes 0 as `y` into CustomMove so you should not expect Notepad to move vertically if you're still doing that

Answer (score 0):

This solved the answer, as window location changes, you must explicitly and mathematically tell where notepad goes;

```
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var xx = Application.Current.MainWindow.Top;
        var yy = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left;
        var zz = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width;
        var zzz = Application.Current.MainWindow.Height;

        var answer = ((yy + zz) + ((yy + zz) * .5));
        var answer2 = (((xx + zzz) + ((xx + zzz) * .5))-zzz);

        int myInt = (int)answer;
        int myIntx = (int)answer2;
        CustomMove(notepadProcess, myInt, myIntx, 0, 0);
    }
```

what the math does is to use the value of the position of main window, and use it to determine notepads x, y.